# How to insert a DEFAULT custom header value to all SoapUI projects?

Tags: groovy, soapui

We have `SoapUI` (Open Source Edition) installed on a windows jumpbox. Many users can login with their accounts, open soapui, import a wadl/wsdl from a dozen of projects and perform testing.

Since the IP is always same, we are unable to find who has sent a request and that is a problem when some destructive requests are made that causes lots of recovery issues (Only authorized users have the access).

Now we want to add http header like `user : ${=System.getenv("USERNAME")}` to the request. It can be a new header property or even a part of user agent.

- We tried to put the property inside HTTP Preferences as a part of user agent string, but it passes the parameter as a string
- We also set a global property but couldn't find a way to insert it as one of HTTP calls by default.

The only ways we found so far was:

1. going to soapui setting of each user and add headers to all requests one by one. (problem: what if user imports more wsdl/wadl later)
2. adding a `startup` script to created projects, so it adds the header by default to everything (problem: users can create new projects any time - please note that each soapui instance is individual)

Comment: It sounds as if your users cannot be trusted? Anything you do in SoapUI can be removed / bypassed by said user. If you only have the unlicensed version, what is the point of having it on a shared computer.

Answer (score 2):

This requirement can easily be fulfilled by the SoapUI's pro software using the feature called Events.

For example, add the header for each request before submitting the web service / rest service call.

However, you mentioned that free version is being used. Wrote an [extension](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions) some time ago, which allows us to do the same in the free edition of SoapUI. There is a [readme](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions/blob/master/README.md) available explaining how to use this. Basically this extension implemented the some of the listeners of SaopUI's API while providing the flexibility to the end users what code should they run(in the form of external file) when the respective event occurs.

Complete the instructions mentioned in the readme.

*Then you need to do is write a groovy script(already given below) to implement your requirement i.e., add the header to the request. That needs to be done in a file with specific file name located in specific directory*(details available there).

In your case, the required code(mostly working sample below) should go into file called `RequestStepBeforeSubmit.groovy`, in order add the user name into each request's header automatically.

Below code snippet should work even if you use the pro software for the same requirement when `SubmitListener.beforeSubmit` event happens.

```groovy
//change the condition if required, should be working for soap/rest types
if (context.getProperty("wsdlRequest")){
   def request = context.getProperty("wsdlRequest").testStep.httpRequest
   def existingHeaders = request.requestHeaders
   def username = System.getProperty('user.name')
   existingHeaders['user'] = [(username)]
   request.requestHeaders = existingHeaders
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it on Monday and let you know

Comment: @ViaSat, did you get chance to try?

Comment: sorry for delay, I followed your instructions but didn't see anything added in the header. My Soapui version is 5.2.1 64bit (Windows) and I checked the SOAPUI_HOME to be correct (I actually copied the groovy files in both root and /bin folder).  you can see the soapui logs here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tYmjPIb6vcT7C94r-8D5Xp20O153SEUvldtizU87hMY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The groovy files should be placed under `SOAPUI_HOME/scripts` directory. It was mentioned to copy scripts directory itself from samples directory to SOAPUI_HOME, but not the groovy files.

Comment: Yes, I did. also added a line to make usename='xxx' to ensure it's not empty. I also tried to use your other code (provided http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-add-addtional-HTTP-header-to-all-the-Rest-Requests/td-p/108768 ) no success.

Comment: so could it be the soapui version? seems your project belong to 4.x  or 3.x era

Comment: I am sure you must be missing some instruction. From just above comment I can say you did not go thru read me carefully.